# Cannot use SSH using Powershell 7

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, powershell-7

When I am trying to use ssh using powershell 7 it throws an error:

```
ssh: The term 'ssh' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

[image: Error in powershell]

But it is working fine for cmd and windows powershell
[image: Working on CMD]
[image: Working on Windows Powershell]

I have also noticed that I cannot change directory to OpenSSH (C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH)
[image: Cannot cd to OpenSSH]

I tried adding Openssh to the system Path, installing openssh client and server but did not work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: when you are logged in as `adnan` what does `where ssh.exe` say the executable resides?

Comment: In powershell 7, it doesn't say anything but in other terminals (cmd) it outputs: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

Comment: Have you checked for existing alias or batch-file with same name: `Get-Alias -Name ssh` ? Probably there are different paths: if 32-bit application includes the "\System32" folder name in a folder path, the system automatically makes a redirection to the SysWOW64 folder

Comment: @Daemon-5, No there is no existing alias. 
`Get-Alias -Name ssh` outputs:
`Get-Alias: This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'ssh' does not exist.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue.

When installing PowerShell, I used to check the box that enables PowerShell remoting. However, this time I did not, and now SSH works.

The solution is as follows:

1. If OpenSSH is not installed (Doesn't even work in cmd) then follow this first: [Get started with OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell)
2. Uninstall PowerShell.
3. Download the installer: [PowerShell Latest Release](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.4.0).
4. During installation, make sure to leave the PowerShell remoting box unchecked.
   [image: Keep PowerShell remoting unchecked]

That was all I had to do.

And here is the screenshot of it working:
[image]